# Swagger does not parse XmlElementWrapper annotation

Tags: java, jersey, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm using Swagger to generate documentation for my jax-rs based API. In one of my models I have the following property:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "clip_list")
@XmlElement(name = "clip")
public List<Clip> mClips = new ArrayList<Clip>();
```

However the JSON model generated in the UI is as follows:

```
"clip": [
    {
    "duration":"",
    "url":"",
    "thumb":"",
    }
]
```

So obviously the XmlElementWrapper annotation is not parsed. How can I force Swagger to correctly nest elements?

Comment: Which version of swagger-core do you use?

Comment: Technically, that output is right. JSON doesn't have wrapper objects, and basically it's an array of "clip" objects. Can you update the question with how you expect the output to look like?

Comment: @webron You are right, I just realized that's now what we use XmlElementWrapper for.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/34993641, but I cannot classify it as duplicate, because https://stackoverflow.com/q/34993641 has no accepted or upvoted answer, so I classify as "Other"...