# Swagger does not parse @XmlElementWrapper annotation

Tags: java, json, jersey, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm using Swagger to generate documentation for my jax-rs based API. In one of my models I have the following property:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "clip_list")
@XmlElement(name = "clip")
public List<Clip> mClips = new ArrayList<Clip>();
```

However the JSON model generated in the UI is as follows:

```
"clip": [
    {
    "duration":"",
    "url":"",
    "thumb":"",
    }
]
```

So obviously the XmlElementWrapper annotation is not parsed. How can I force Swagger to correctly nest elements?

The output should be like :

```
"clip_list": [
    {
    "duration":"",
    "url":"",
    "thumb":"",
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The output looks correct. For more details, have a look at this [issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/505) in the Swagger repository.

You could try using the [`@ApiModelProperty`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations#apimodelproperty) annotation to manipulate the metadata of a model property, as following:

```java
@XmlElement(name = "clip")
@ApiModelProperty(value = "clip_list")
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "clip_list")
public List<Clip> mClips = new ArrayList<Clip>();
```

For more details about the [`@ApiModelProperty`](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.3.12/apidocs/com/wordnik/swagger/annotations/ApiModelProperty.html) API, have a look at the [javadocs](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.3.12/apidocs/com/wordnik/swagger/annotations/ApiModelProperty.html).

Answer (score 0):

Soved the issue. Just exclude the following dependencies from swagger dependency.

```
          <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
```

After excluding these i was able to get the annotations working.